# Reactjs vite i want to pass data between page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, vite

i tried to make a pass data between page but it's always nothing in "toko" page i tried to fix it but still error so i want to ask in stack overflow to fix this issue

home.jsx is the main page

toko.jsx is the page i want to insert data from index.js

index.js is the data that i want to pass the data to toko.jsx

app.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Home from "./component/home";
import Toko from "./component/toko";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";

function Introduction({ nama, kelas }){
  return (

  <div className="App">
    <h1>halo, nama saya {nama} dan saya kelas {kelas} </h1>
  </div>
  );
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" Component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/toko/:id" component={Toko}/>
       </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
}
}

export default App
```

home.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Profil from '../assets/Aaa.png';
import keyboard from '../assets/rexus.jpg';
import mouse from '../assets/logitech.jpg';
import controller from '../assets/xbox.jpg';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from '../header.jsx';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { semuakelas } from '../data/index.js';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import CardGroup from 'react-bootstrap/CardGroup';
import AOS from 'aos';
import 'aos/dist/aos.css'; // You can also use <link> for styles
// ..
AOS.init();

function Introduction({ nama, kelas }){
    return (
  
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className='nama'>halo, nama saya {nama} dan saya kelas {kelas} </h1>
    </div>
    );
  }
  
  
  const Home = props => {
    const [products,setproduct,] = useState(0)
    

    function increaseOrderCount(){
        setproduct(products + 1)
    }

    function decreaseOrderCount(){
        if (products > 0){
            setproduct(products - 1)
        }
    }
    return (
      <>
      <Header />
      <img className='profil' src={Profil} alt=""/>
      <Introduction nama="1" kelas="rpl-Xi_a"/>
      <div className='card-product'>
      <Container>

<Row md={4}>
  {semuakelas.map((kelas) => {
      return(
  <Col>
  <Card data-aos-delay={kelas.delay} data-aos="fade-up" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
  <Card.Img className='cimg' variant="top" src={kelas.image} />
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title className='ctext'>{kelas.name}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text className='ctext'>
        {kelas.price}
      </Card.Text>
      <div className='Home'>
      <Button className='ctext' variant="black" onClick={decreaseOrderCount}>-</Button>
      <span className='ctext'>{products}</span>
      <Button className='ctext' variant="black" onClick={increaseOrderCount}>+</Button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i className={kelas.star1}></i>
        <i className={kelas.star2}></i>
        <i className={kelas.star3}></i>
        <i className={kelas.star4}></i>
        <i className={kelas.star5}></i>
      </div>
      <Link
              to={{
                pathname: `/toko/${kelas.id}`,
                state: { semuakelas: kelas }
              }}
            >
              <button>View</button>
            </Link>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
  </Col>
        );
      })}
  <Col>
  <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
    <Card.Img className='cimg' variant="top" src={controller} />
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title className='ctext'>XBOX Controller</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text className='ctext'>
        RP 700.000
      </Card.Text>
      <Button variant="primary" href="/toko/">Go somewhere</Button>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
  </Col>
  </Row>

  
  </Container>
  </div>
      </>
    )
  };
  
  export default Home
```

toko.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Toko = (_) => {
  const { state } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <strong>Id:</strong> {state.semuakelas.id}{" "}
        </div>
        <div>
          <strong>Name:</strong> {state.semuakelas.title}{" "}
        </div>
      </div>

      <Link to="/">
        <button>Back</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Toko;
```

index.js (database)

```
import rexus from "../assets/rexus.jpg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const semuakelas = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image: rexus,
        star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
        title: "Rexus Legionare MX 10",
        price: "Rp. 499.000",
        buy: "Beli Kelas",
        delay: "100",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        image: rexus,
        star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
        title: "Character Illustration with Adobe Illustrator",
        price: "Rp. 300.000",
        buy: "Beli Kelas",
        delay: "200",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        image: rexus,
        star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
        title: "Character Illustration with Adobe Illustrator",
        price: "Rp. 300.000",
        buy: "Beli Kelas",
        delay: "300",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        image: rexus,
        star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
        title: "Character Illustration with Adobe Illustrator",
        price: "Rp. 300.000",
        buy: "Beli Kelas",
        delay: "400",
      },
      {
      id: 5,
      image: rexus,
      star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
      title: "Rexus Legionare MX 10",
      price: "Rp. 499.000",
      buy: "Beli Kelas",
      delay: "100",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      image: rexus,
      star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
      title: "Character Illustration with Adobe Illustrator",
      price: "Rp. 300.000",
      buy: "Beli Kelas",
      delay: "200",
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      image: rexus,
      star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
      title: "Character Illustration with Adobe Illustrator",
      price: "Rp. 300.000",
      buy: "Beli Kelas",
      delay: "300",
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      image: rexus,
      star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
      star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
      title: "Character Illustration with Adobe Illustrator",
      price: "Rp. 300.000",
      buy: "Beli Kelas",
      delay: "400",
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        image: rexus,
        star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
        title: "Character Illustration with Adobe Illustrator",
        price: "Rp. 300.000",
        buy: "Beli Kelas",
        delay: "300",
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        image: rexus,
        star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
        star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
        title: "Character Illustration with Adobe Illustrator",
        price: "Rp. 300.000",
        buy: "Beli Kelas",
        delay: "400",
      },
];
```